# Using Redactor as a WSIWYG editor with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redactor

I'm trying to add a few simple WYSIWYG fields to a form. Initially redactor was working perfectly but somewhere along the line I lost the toolbars. I think that somehow the original code was overidden by other members in the team but I don't know and I'm not comfortable enough with Git to go back and check.

This is in edit_content.html.erb

```
<div id="edit_form">

     <fieldset>
         <span><legend><%= @category.title.capitalize %> Content</legend></span>
             <div class="field">
                 <%= f.label :statement %> <br />
                 <%= f.text_area :statement, rows: 10, cols: 80, :class=>'redactor_text' %>
             </div>

             <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :quote %> <br />
                  <%= f.text_area :quote, row: 10, cols: 80, :class=>'redactor_text' %>
             </div>

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And this is in assets\javascripts\redactor-rails\config.js

```
 $('.redactor').redactor(
   { "imageUpload":"/redactor_rails/pictures?" + params,
     "imageGetJson":"/redactor_rails/pictures",
     "fileUpload":"/redactor_rails/documents?" + params,
     "fileGetJson":"/redactor_rails/documents",
     "path":"/assets/redactor-rails",
     "css":"style.css"
  });
$('.redactor_text').redactor(
  { buttons: ["html", "|", "formatting", "|", "bold", "italic", "underline", "deleted", "|",
   "unorderedlist", "orderedlist", "outdent", "indent", "|", "image", "video", "file", "link", "table", "|",
   "fontcolor", "backcolor", "|", "alignment", "|", "horizontalrule"]
});
```

I initially chose redactor because I've heard it can work with paperclip and I'd like to use that functionality later on so any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @Nich I added the function .redactor_text

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do this?

```
var buttons = ["html", "|", "formatting", "|", "bold", "italic", "underline", "deleted", "|",
   "unorderedlist", "orderedlist", "outdent", "indent", "|", "image", "video", "file", "link", "table", "|",
   "fontcolor", "backcolor", "|", "alignment", "|", "horizontalrule"];

 $('.redactor').redactor(
   { "imageUpload":"/redactor_rails/pictures?" + params,
     "imageGetJson":"/redactor_rails/pictures",
     "fileUpload":"/redactor_rails/documents?" + params,
     "fileGetJson":"/redactor_rails/documents",
     "path":"/assets/redactor-rails",
     "css":"style.css",
     "buttons": buttons

  });
```

how you think?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be redactor, not redactor-text if you want redactor to show properly.

```
... :class=>' redactor redactor_text' %>
```

I'm currently struggling with customising the toolbar with custom buttons. But I hope my answer helps with getting the toolbar showing again.